# How to return data from Ember Controller to my component inside View?

Tags: ember.js, momentjs

How can i return data from my Controller to my component inside View?

This is my component

```
{{#each model as |lineItem index|}}
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{global.daterange-picker 
                     startDateMoment=startDate(lineItem.date)
                     singleDatePicker=true 
                     drops='down' 
                     value=lineItem.date
                     name='date'
                     class='edit-row-element'}}
        <td>
     </tr>
{{/each}}
```

This is my controller

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import moment from 'moment';
export default Component.extend({

  startDate(date) {
      // body...
      return moment(date);
  }

});
```

This is my date format

```
lineItem.date = Tue Jun 03 2003 01:35:16 GMT+0700 (ICT)
```

But i always got an error for `startDateMoment=startDate(lineItem.date)`

So any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: try  `startDateMoment=(moment lineItem.date)`  Remember you cant call `startDate` function in like you did

Comment: I got "Assertion Failed: A helper named "moment" could not be found"

Comment: You need to.`ember install ember-moment`

Comment: I can not do that for now so is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Create helper to return formatted date,

helpers/formatted-date.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import moment from 'moment';
export function formattedDate(params) {
  return moment(params[0]);
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(formattedDate);
```

Use that helper `formatted-date` to format `lineItem.date`

```
{{global.daterange-picker  startDateMoment=(formatted-date lineItem.date) }}
```